# Robot Framework + AutoIt: Dictionary does not contain key

Tags: python, dictionary, autoit, robotframework

I am currently toying around with the [AutoIt](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/) library for [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/), so I'm doing the typical "my first" Robot GUI test and testing the Calculator! Unfortunately my below code generates the error: `Dictionary does not contain key 'View Scientific'.`. This occurs in the *Start Calculator* keyword. It seems that whenever I call *Select Calculator Menu Item* I get an error.

```
*** Settings ***
| Documentation    | Tests AutoIt Library
| Suite Setup      | Start Calculator
| Library          | AutoItLibrary
| Library          | Collections
| Library          | String
| Variables        | CalculatorGUIMap.py


*** Test Cases ***
| Integer Addition
| | Click Buttons | 2 2 + 2 =
| | Win Wait | Calculator | 24
| | ${Ans}= | Get Answer
| | Should Be Equal As Numbers | ${Ans} | 24


*** Keywords ***
| Start Calculator
| | Run | calc.exe
| | Wait For Active Window | Calculator
| | Get Calculator Version
| | Select Calculator Menu Item | View Scientific
| | Send | 12345
| | ${Result} | ${ErrMsg} = | Run Keyword And Ignore Error | Win Wait
| | ...       | Calculator  | 12345
| | Run Keyword If | "${Result}"=="FAIL" | Select Calculator Menu Item | View Digit grouping
| | Win Wait | Calculator | 12345
| | Click Button | Clear

| Click Button
| | [Arguments]     | ${Button Text}
| | ${ButtonName} = | Get From Dictionary | ${GUIMAP} | ${ButtonText}
| | Control Click   | Calculator          | ${EMPTY}  | ${ButtonName}

| Click Buttons
| | [Arguments] | ${ButtonNames}
| | @{Buttons}= | Split String  | ${ButtonNames}
| | :FOR        | ${ButtonName} | IN             | @{Buttons}
| |             | Click Button  | ${ButtonName}

| Select Calculator Menu Item
| | [Arguments] | ${MenuItem}
| | ${AltKeys}= | Get From Dictionary | ${MENUMAP} | ${MenuItem}
| | Send  | {ALTDOWN}
| | Sleep | 1
| | Send  | ${AltKeys}
| | Send  | {ALTUP}

| Get Calculator Version
| | Send  | {ALTDOWN}
| | Sleep | 1
| | Send  | ha
| | Send  | {ALTUP}
| | Win Wait Active | About Calculator | Version
| | ${WinText}= | Control Get Text | About Calculator | Version | 13579
| | ${WinText2}= | Run Keyword If   | "Version" not in "${WinText}" | Control Get Text
| | ...          | About Calculator | Version                       | Static4
| | ${WinText}= | Set Variable If | "version" in "${WinText2}" | ${WinText2}
| | ...         | ${WinText}
| | Run Keyword If | "Version" not in "${WinText}" | Fail | Can't find Calculator version
| | ${GUIMAP}= | Set Variable If | "5.1" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_51}
| | ${GUIMAP}= | Set Variable If | "6.0" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_60}
| | ...        | ${GUIMAP}
| | ${GUIMAP}= | Set Variable If | "6.1" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_61}
| | ...        | ${GUIMAP}
| | Run Keyword If | ${GUIMAP}== None | Fail | Calculator version not supported: ${WinText}
| | Set Suite Variable | ${GUIMAP}
| | ${MENUMAP}= | Set Variable If | "5.1" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_51}
| | ${MENUMAP}= | Set Variable If | "6.0" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_60}
| | ...          | ${MENUMAP}
| | ${MENUMAP}= | Set Variable If | "6.1" in "${WinText}" | ${GUIMAP_61}
| | ...          | ${MENUMAP}
| | Set Suite Variable | ${MENUMAP}
| | Control Click | About Calculator | Version | Button1

| Get Answer
| | Select Calculator menu Item | Edit Copy
| | ${Answer}= | Clip Get
| | [Return] | ${Answer}
```

What is the reason for this keyword generating errors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dictionary does not contain key 'View Scientific'" should be pretty self-explanatory. You're trying to use the key `"View Scientific"` as a key to a dictionary, and that dictionary doesn't have that key.

In your case you have a dictionary named `${MENUMAP}` that apparently does *not* have the key `"View Scientific"`. You need to figure out why your map is missing this key. A simple thing to do is to log the dictionary, which will tell you what keys it  has.

Comment: Where I'd copied and pasted the variable settings for different versions I had just used the GUI mapping when I needed to use the menu mapping. Thanks for highlighting this!